# How to combine three queries in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three queries.

First Query:

```
SELECT SUM(transaction.price)
FROM transaction
WHERE transaction_type='sell' AND transaction.customer_id=1
```

Second Query:

```
SELECT SUM(transaction.payment)
FROM transaction
WHERE transaction_type='sell' AND transaction.customer_id=1
```

Third Query:

```
SELECT SUM(transaction.price)
FROM transaction
WHERE transaction_type='return' AND transaction.customer_id=1
```

All of the queries working separately but I want to combine these queries. And my output should be like 'expected result'.

```
expected result= ((result of the second query)+(result of the third query)) - (result of the first query)
```

Note: `customer_id` is used as a foreign key.

Comment: Use `case` expressions to do conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql will evaluate a boolean expression like `transaction_type='sell'` as `0` or `1` for false or true so you can simplify the query like this:

```
SELECT 
  SUM((transaction_type='sell') * (payment - price)) + 
  SUM((transaction_type='return') * price)
FROM transaction
WHERE customer_id=1
```

or simpler:

```
SELECT 
  SUM((transaction_type='sell') * (payment - price) + (transaction_type='return') * price)
FROM transaction
WHERE customer_id=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN transaction_type = 'sell'   THEN payment ELSE 0 END) +
    SUM(CASE WHEN transaction_type = 'return' THEN price ELSE 0 END) -
    SUM(CASE WHEN transaction_type = 'sell'   THEN price ELSE 0 END)
FROM `transaction`
WHERE customer_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use if to filter which columns you want to sum.

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(transaction_type = 'sell', transaction.price, 0)) sell_sum,
    SUM(IF(transaction_type = 'sell', transaction.payment, 0)) payment_sum,
    SUM(IF(transaction_type = 'return', transaction.price, 0)) return_sum
FROM transaction
WHERE transaction_type IN('sell', 'return') AND transaction.customer_id = 1
```